# Error/warning message in PHP "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: php

I am using the below PHP code but it is generating an error/warning message:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1

The code runs as expected.

```
while(1) {
    while($data = fgets($irc, 128)) {

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);

        if($ex[0] == "PING"){
            fputs($irc, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        }

        if($ex[1] == "265"){
            $lusers = str_replace(',', '', $ex[8]);
            $gusers = $ex[10];
        }

    }
}
```

I cannot see what is wrong in the code. It is running as expected so why is the error/warning message being generated?

Suggestion to use `print_r($ex)` shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SeIKVfMCuzNTGjZ

)
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
```

Should I just add a check that `$ex > 0` or is there a better way?

I updated code so it only runs if `$ex > 0`:

```
while(1) {
    while($data = fgets($irc, 128)) {

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);

        if($ex[0] == "PING"){
            fputs($irc, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        }

        if(count($ex) > 0){

            if($ex[1] == "265"){
                $lusers = str_replace(',', '', $ex[8]);
                $gusers = $ex[10];
            }

        }

    }
}
?>
```

but I still get the error/warning message. How is it possible?

Comment: @Rizier123 I looked at that. I couldn't see how the answer there is relevant to my code here.

Comment: What is the contents of `$irc`?

Comment: Just do `print_r($ex);` and you know why you get this warning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if(isset($ex[1]) && $ex[1] == "265") {
    //do stuff

} else {
    echo "Index doesn't exist!";
}
```